# Bypassing VPN while using a kill switch - DD-WRT

Tags: iptables, openvpn, dd-wrt

I have setup OpenVPN on my R7800 router to connect to my VPN provider.

I want to bypass the tunnel for some sites.
For the sake of question let it be www.whatsmyip.com

I have two ip rules acting as kill switch for my VPN connection added to "Firewall" script:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -o $WAN_IF -m state --state NEW -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
iptables -I FORWARD -o $WAN_IF -p tcp -m state --state NEW -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
```

Actually a bit more complicated since I use Policy Based Routing (PBR), but it shouldn't matter. [Reference](http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=288852)

I have found that bypassing the tunnel for specific domain names is possible using the following commands:

```
allow﻿-pull-fqd﻿n
route www.whatsmyip.com 255.255.255.255 net_gateway﻿
```

[Reference](https://airvpn.org/forums/topic/19781-bypass-vpn-for-specific-domain-names-netflix-hulu-via-custom-configuration-in-openvpn-tomato-dd-wrtrouter/)

I have entered the above to "OpenVPN Client --> Additional Config" field.

The above seems to work, since the kill switch kicks in and forbids the connection and page is not loading.

So, I need to add a firewall rule to allow this connection.
The following rule is entered below the kill switch rules:

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -d whatsmyip.org -j ACCEPT
```

I came up to this reading [this](https://serverfault.com/a/218800)

Apparently, the rule I came up is not right.

How can I properly modify the above rule in order to bypass the kill switch successfully?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting the answer here for clarity.

```
iptables -I FORWARD -d whatsmyip.org -o $(get_wanface) -j ACCEPT
```

No need for `allow-pull-fqdn`, it is default in OpenVPN 2.4